# How to run nginx load balancer with upstream random directive in docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    hostname: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 8088:80
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./index.php:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php
  php7:
    hostname: php7
    container_name: php7
    image: php:7.4-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./index.php:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php
  php8:
    image: php:8.1-fpm-alpine
    hostname: php8
    container_name: php8
    volumes:
      - ./index.php:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php
```

This is `default.conf`:

```
upstream php {
  random two;
  server php7:9000;
  server php8:9000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /dev/stderr  main;
    error_log /dev/stderr;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.php info.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php;
    }
    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
#  location ~ \.php(/|$) {
#    fastcgi_hide_header Content-Type;
#    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
#    fastcgi_pass php7:9000;
#    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
#    include fastcgi_params;
#    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
#  }
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}
}
```

But when I type `http://IP:8088/index.php`, I get 404 error in web browser, but there's no log in nginx to troubleshoot more.

I want to test a simple load balancer in nginx, so that when I type `http://IP:8088/index.php`, one time I see php8.1 and another time I see 7.4.

First of all, is that right what I'm doing?

Second, how may I have it?

Comment: The docker compose file along with configuration files is working for me. You can check the logs in your console itself where you're running the `docker-compose up`.

Comment: @RahulSharma yes it works fine, but no `php` file is loaded in web browser. I see no logs (neither error nor access) when running `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you need to tell `php-fpm` certain params in the `location ~ \.php$ {}` block to be able to find the `index.php` file. The correct nginx conf file that worked for me:

```
upstream php {
  random two;
  server php7:9000;
  server php8:9000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /dev/stderr  main;
    error_log /dev/stderr;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.php info.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass php;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Please note that you need to move the `root` directive outside the `location /` block so that `$document_root` is properly set.